# Need to copy files from cdrom, to a mounted USB drive (TomTom) in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, usb-2, gps

I would like to write a daemon/batch/script...that listens to the HAL for events and then launches a script once a usb device (TomTom gps) is plugged in. This script will be placed on the cdrom disk for the autorun.inf to automatically copy files from the cdrom disk to the usb TomTom device, once it's inserted into the usb port...Thank You